# Why convert to a function

Tags: scala

I have following code snippet:

```
def foo(x:Int, y:Int, z:Int) : Int = x * y * z
def boo(x: Int) : Int = foo(10, 20, x)
```

Look at the second line, how can I know as scala beginner, that the second return a function?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Perhaps edit this and add sample code that uses these functions along with the output that you're expecting.

Comment: The second line does not return a function; it returns an `Int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
def boo(x: Int) : Int = foo(10, 20, x)
```

it is not returning the function call `foo`, it returns `Int`, which is what you have between `:` and `=`

`foo(10, 20, x)` is the implementation of boo function, which makes sense considering that foo also returns Int.

I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Why can I just give an x to foo? I'm coming from imperative language and that is so wired for me.

Comment: Because foo is declared to accept 3 parameters, i.e. `def foo(x:Int, y:Int, z:Int)` so x, y and z. That also applies to imperative languages :)